# IOS crash in App Store build

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, appcelerator, symbolicatecrash

I have device logs crash report from iphone 4S.how to find the error from my crash report.
IOS version 8.3
This is not a reproducible crash.It occurs rarely and no specific senario.
Pelase help me to find out.

```
{
    "crash": {
        "diagnosis": "Possible zombie in call: -[SRHubProxy release]\nOriginated at or in a subcall of _mh_execute_header",
        "error": {
            "address": 2439342019,
            "mach": {
                "code": 1,
                "code_name": "KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS",
                "exception": 1,
                "exception_name": "EXC_BAD_ACCESS",
                "subcode": 0
            },
            "signal": {
                "code": 0,
                "code_name": "SEGV_NOOP",
                "name": "SIGSEGV",
                "signal": 11
            },
            "type": "mach"
        },
        "threads": [
            {
                "backtrace": {
                    "contents": [
                        {
                            "instruction_addr": 956731238,
                            "object_addr": 956653568,
                            "object_name": "libobjc.A.dylib",
                            "symbol_addr": 956731232,
                            "symbol_name": "objc_msgSend"
                        },
                        {
                            "instruction_addr": 720172673,
                            "object_addr": 720117760,
                            "object_name": "CoreFoundation",
                            "symbol_addr": 720172076,
                            "symbol_name": "CFRelease"
                        },
                        {
                            "instruction_addr": 720276233,
                            "object_addr": 720117760,
                            "object_name": "CoreFoundation",
                            "symbol_addr": 720276096,
                            "symbol_name": "<redacted>"
                        },
                        {
                            "instruction_addr": 956788055,
                            "object_addr": 956653568,
                            "object_name": "libobjc.A.dylib",
                            "symbol_addr": 956787888,
                            "symbol_name": "<redacted>"
                        },
                        {
                            "instruction_addr": 956677517,
                            "object_addr": 956653568,
                            "object_name": "libobjc.A.dylib",
                            "symbol_addr": 956677400,
                            "symbol_name": "<redacted>"
                        },
                        {
                            "instruction_addr": 956716547,
                            "object_addr": 956653568,
                            "object_name": "libobjc.A.dylib",
                            "symbol_addr": 956716512,
                            "symbol_name": "objc_destructInstance"
                        },
                        {
                            "instruction_addr": 956716583,
                            "object_addr": 956653568,
                            "object_name": "libobjc.A.dylib",
                            "symbol_addr": 956716568,
                            "symbol_name": "object_dispose"
                        },
                        {
                            "instruction_addr": 6011169,
                            "object_addr": 704512,
                            "object_name": "MYAPP",
                            "symbol_addr": 704512,
                            "symbol_name": "_mh_execute_header"
                        },
                        {
                            "instruction_addr": 956788055,
                            "object_addr": 956653568,
                            "object_name": "libobjc.A.dylib",
                            "symbol_addr": 956787888,
                            "symbol_name": "<redacted>"
                        },
                        {
                            "instruction_addr": 5421543,
                            "object_addr": 704512,
                            "object_name": "MYAPP",
                            "symbol_addr": 704512,
                            "symbol_name": "_mh_execute_header"
                        },
                        {
                            "instruction_addr": 962358403,
                            "object_addr": 962351104,
                            "object_name": "libdispatch.dylib",
                            "symbol_addr": 962358392,
                            "symbol_name": "<redacted>"
                        },
                        {
                            "instruction_addr": 962410603,
                            "object_addr": 962351104,
                            "object_name": "libdispatch.dylib",
                            "symbol_addr": 962409228,
                            "symbol_name": "<redacted>"
                        },
                        {
                            "instruction_addr": 962414755,
                            "object_addr": 962351104,
                            "object_name": "libdispatch.dylib",
                            "symbol_addr": 962414648,
                            "symbol_name": "<redacted>"
                        },
                        {
                            "instruction_addr": 963939753,
                            "object_addr": 963936256,
                            "object_name": "libsystem_pthread.dylib",
                            "symbol_addr": 963939084,
                            "symbol_name": "_pthread_wqthread"
                        }
                    ],
                    "skipped": 0
                },
                "crashed": true,
                "current_thread": false,
                "dispatch_queue": "com.apple.root.background-qos",
                "index": 18,
                "notable_addresses": {
                    "r0": {
                        "address": 377088480,
                        "last_deallocated_obj": "SRHubProxy",
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "unsigned __int128"
                    },
                    "r1": {
                        "address": 904568254,
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "release"
                    },
                    "r11": {
                        "address": 377034864,
                        "class": "__NSDictionaryM",
                        "ivars": {
                            "_mutations": 2,
                            "_size": 0
                        },
                        "last_deallocated_obj": "NSSortDescriptor",
                        "type": "objc_object"
                    },
                    "r2": {
                        "address": 966640552,
                        "class": "__NSCFType",
                        "ivars": {},
                        "type": "objc_object"
                    },
                    "r5": {
                        "address": 377088484,
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "gned __int128"
                    },
                    "r6": {
                        "address": 377088480,
                        "last_deallocated_obj": "SRHubProxy",
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "unsigned __int128"
                    },
                    "r8": {
                        "address": 966610768,
                        "class": "__NSCFType",
                        "type": "objc_class"
                    },
                    "stack@0xb08de0": {
                        "address": 374766448,
                        "last_deallocated_obj": "__NSDictionaryM",
                        "type": "unknown"
                    },
                    "stack@0xb08de8": {
                        "address": 966613168,
                        "class": "__NSCFType",
                        "ivars": {},
                        "type": "objc_object"
                    },
                    "stack@0xb08df0": {
                        "address": 966613168,
                        "class": "__NSCFType",
                        "ivars": {},
                        "type": "objc_object"
                    },
                    "stack@0xb08e0c": {
                        "address": 786090233,
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "name"
                    },
                    "stack@0xb08e10": {
                        "address": 786074369,
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "UTF8String"
                    },
                    "stack@0xb08e14": {
                        "address": 786110722,
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "reason"
                    },
                    "stack@0xb08e30": {
                        "address": 377088484,
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "gned __int128"
                    },
                    "stack@0xb08e34": {
                        "address": 374766448,
                        "last_deallocated_obj": "__NSDictionaryM",
                        "type": "unknown"
                    },
                    "stack@0xb08e40": {
                        "address": 377034864,
                        "class": "__NSDictionaryM",
                        "ivars": {
                            "_mutations": 2,
                            "_size": 0
                        },
                        "last_deallocated_obj": "NSSortDescriptor",
                        "type": "objc_object"
                    }
                },
                "registers": {
                    "basic": {
                        "cpsr": 805306416,
                        "ip": 966461428,
                        "lr": 720172673,
                        "pc": 956731238,
                        "r0": 377088480,
                        "r1": 904568254,
                        "r10": 376887340,
                        "r11": 377034864,
                        "r2": 966640552,
                        "r3": 4095,
                        "r4": 560326604,
                        "r5": 377088484,
                        "r6": 377088480,
                        "r7": 11570768,
                        "r8": 966610768,
                        "r9": 2439342007,
                        "sp": 11570696
                    },
                    "exception": {
                        "exception": 0,
                        "far": 2439342019,
                        "fsr": 5
                    }
                },
                "stack": {
                    "contents": "707B561602000000B0589D3900D87616B0589D3900D876160000000000000000508EB00013F9EC2A21B95B00F9C8DA2E018BDA2E0219DB2EFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0700000000D8761600000000FF2789E9E4E97916707B561620D876162CD876167018791603000000A0F27916A0F279167C8EB000098BEE2A",
                    "dump_end": 11570776,
                    "dump_start": 11570656,
                    "grow_direction": "-",
                    "overflow": false,
                    "stack_pointer": 11570696
                }
            },
            {
                "backtrace": {
                    "contents": [
                        {
                            "instruction_addr": 963426752,
                            "object_addr": 963338240,
                            "object_name": "libsystem_kernel.dylib",
                            "symbol_addr": 963426744,
                            "symbol_name": "__workq_kernreturn"
                        },
                        {
                            "instruction_addr": 963939877,
                            "object_addr": 963936256,
                            "object_name": "libsystem_pthread.dylib",
                            "symbol_addr": 963939084,
                            "symbol_name": "_pthread_wqthread"
                        }
                    ],
                    "skipped": 0
                },
                "crashed": false,
                "current_thread": false,
                "index": 19,
                "registers": {
                    "basic": {
                        "cpsr": 1073741840,
                        "ip": 368,
                        "lr": 963939877,
                        "pc": 963426752,
                        "r0": 4,
                        "r1": 0,
                        "r10": 962414649,
                        "r11": 21,
                        "r2": 0,
                        "r3": 0,
                        "r4": 91226112,
                        "r5": 2147485951,
                        "r6": 62791,
                        "r7": 91226080,
                        "r8": 65536,
                        "r9": 1005712320,
                        "sp": 91226052
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "process": {},
    "report": {
        "id": "1DD54528-AB65-4E03-AA04-9F5A31F590EF",
        "process_name": "MYAPP",
        "timestamp": "2016-05-24T14:16:43Z",
        "type": "standard",
        "version": {
            "major": 3,
            "minor": 0
        }
    },
    "system": {
        "CFBundleExecutable": "MYAPP",
        "CFBundleExecutablePath": "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/3613DF54-5D7A-4CF3-80C7-BA8645055890/MYAPP.app/MYAPP",
        "CFBundleIdentifier": "com.ca.tridentapp",
        "CFBundleName": "MYAPP",
        "CFBundleShortVersionString": "1.2.1",
        "CFBundleVersion": "1.2.1.0",
        "app_start_time": "2016-05-24T14:14:45Z",
        "app_uuid": "C7BEE99A-23FB-37FD-AE35-4F709C17F1DB",
        "application_stats": {
            "active_time_since_last_crash": 97319.4,
            "active_time_since_launch": 57261.5,
            "application_active": false,
            "application_in_foreground": true,
            "background_time_since_last_crash": 248.658,
            "background_time_since_launch": 0,
            "launches_since_last_crash": 3,
            "sessions_since_last_crash": 4,
            "sessions_since_launch": 1
        },
        "binary_cpu_subtype": 9,
        "binary_cpu_type": 12,
        "boot_time": "2016-05-23T04:36:03Z",
        "cpu_arch": "armv7f",
        "cpu_subtype": 10,
        "cpu_type": 12,
        "device_app_hash": "ff2f1547abd2cf5c9592b7eb795b0918d8ef26e9",
        "jailbroken": false,
        "kernel_version": "Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Sun Mar 29 19:45:16 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2784.20.34~2/RELEASE_ARM_S5L8940X",
        "machine": "iPhone4,1",
        "memory": {
            "free": 27492352,
            "size": 529481728,
            "usable": 230555648
        },
        "model": "N94AP",
        "os_version": "12F70",
        "parent_process_id": 1,
        "parent_process_name": "launchd",
        "process_id": 5883,
        "process_name": "MYAPP",
        "system_name": "iPhone OS",
        "system_version": "8.3",
        "time_zone": "EDT"
    }
}
```

Thank in advance..

Answer (score 3):

This crash is related to "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" to detect the exact error we can take help of the Zombie Object.

We need to enable it from the Edit Scheme -> Select Run from left panel -> Select Diagnostics tab -> Select Enable Zombie Objects from Memory Management.

[image]

Also we can symbolicate the crash report to detect the exact function in which the crash detected along with the specific line.

Reference Link : [Steps to symbolicate the crash report](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4954949/2113743)